# Vagrant + Laravel - Not displaying PHP errors

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

I've followed this tutorial to set up Vagrant, Virtual Box:

https://gist.github.com/JeffreyWay/af0ee7311abfde3e3b73

I've set up a Laravel project using composer and everything appears to work fine.

The issue is that it doesn't seem to display any PHP errors. I've made sure that `display_errors = On` in the php.ini, confirmed that with `phpinfo()` and I've even added

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

In `public/index.php` but nothing is displayed. I've purposefully written syntax errors to force an error but it displays a blank page.

Comment: Why not just use [Laravel's Homestead](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead)?

Comment: @natzim because I'm looking for a custom environment

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a permission problem in your vagrant machine.
You need to set the proper permissions.
Navigate to your vagrant directory and try this:

> vagrant ssh
>   chmod -R 777 app/storage

Comment: Yea I tried that. The application works fine, no blank page, only when there's an error.

Comment: Go to app/config/app.php and set 'debug' => true

Comment: Make sure that the VirtualHost configuration is correct, the server is allowed to override the default config with the local `.htaccess` files. Check your Apache version to determine whether to use `Allow from all` or `Require all granted`. Also have a look at your `/etc/hosts` file. Don’t forget to restart the server after touching its config files!

Comment: Permission issue on my MAC caused this issue. Did a chmod 777 laravel.log and errors are now showing up fine.